# ModalPopupExtender From AJAX ToolKit in asp.net4.0

Tags: panel, imagebutton, modalpopupextender

i have one image button on page,on click event of this imagebutton i have called one ModalPopupExtender, having definition as 
(Panel3 contains one gridview and one button whereas gridview gets filled in codebehind)
But when i click the imagebutton, for 1st time it displays Panel3 with only button for 2seconds and then page gets reloaded automatically and again Panel3 displays with gridview,why this is happning i do not understand

i need to do is, as soon as i click on ImageButton the popup should be displayed with gridview and button....please help me as soon a possible